# Как отследить с помощью MutationObserver появление элемента div и добавить на него изображение img?

Tags: javascript

В определённый момент на странице появляется элемент `<div class= "tooltip-list">`. Как отследить его появление и добавить к нему картину `<img src="cat.gif" alt=cat" title="cat">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно написать функцию обработчик для `MutationsObserver`, который следит за изменениями в DOM дереве, и когда элемент  добавляется в DOM, он добавляет изображение  к этому элементу. После добавления изображения наблюдение отключается, чтобы избежать повторных действий.

```js
// Функция, которая будет вызвана при появлении элемента
function handleMutation(mutationsList, observer) {
  for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
      // Перебираем добавленные элементы
      for (const addedNode of mutation.addedNodes) {
        // Проверяем, является ли добавленный элемент div с классом "tooltip-list"
        if (addedNode instanceof HTMLElement && addedNode.classList.contains('tooltip-list')) {
          // Создаем элемент img
          const imgElement = document.createElement('img');
          imgElement.src = 'cat.gif';
          imgElement.alt = 'cat';
          imgElement.title = 'cat';

          // Добавляем изображение к элементу div
          addedNode.appendChild(imgElement);

          // Отключаем наблюдение, так как элемент уже найден
          observer.disconnect();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Создаем новый экземпляр MutationObserver
const observer = new MutationObserver(handleMutation);

// Начинаем наблюдение за изменениями в DOM
observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
```

Comment: E1mir, спасибо код работает.

Comment: E1mir, а можно ещё в код событие onclick добавить?

Comment: Так добавьте туда куда вам нужно, это ведь просто :)

Comment: E1mir,  ну да оказалось легко imgElement.onclick = function() { };